# asp.net MVC - variable value is not updated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The variable which is used in the view is not updated when changing value.

The following steps I have done.

1. I have declared the variable in the view.
2. Then I changed the variable value before rendering in the view. That is updated.
3. After rendered, I have updated the variable value immediately. Then view value is not updated with the latest value.

Here I had a confusion because the string is the object. So whenever the value has been changed for the string, then the reference value should be changed. Why it is not changed in the view.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                Declare and update variable value
                @{
                   string value="test value";

                    if(true)
                    {
                          value="value has been checked once";
                    }

                    <div>
                        @value
                    </div>

                   if(true)
                    {
                          value="Again value has been checked once";
                    }

                }
            </div>
```

**Output**:

```
Declare and update variable value
value has been checked once
```

Please refer the sample
https://dotnetfiddle.net/GlmBBk

Comment: It will be difficult to go through your all program and give you the results. So we prefer to include your issue here itself instead of putting it in .net fiddle. Show us your effort and let us know where do you need help

Comment: from your example it seems you are looking to achieve a MVVM pattern in MVC. You are changing the variable value only you have to renter it to view if you want to see it in browser. The first value is already renter in the view.And the second change you did for variable only

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Don't look all the code. Please look only the view.. not any code from  the fiddle

Comment: Still the same thought from myside. You cannot expect this kind of behavior from MVC. You have changed the value and you have rentered it to a div that happend and now the value is there in the view.So its just like writing something like <div> hi</div> now. It wont be changed if you have updated value variable again.The value of that variable will change and you can see it if you put breakpoint there if you want to see that in view you have to again write <div>@variable</div>

Comment: Thank you .. understand. I had confusion with the concept of angular

Answer (score -1):

As the title implies you ought to use MVC. In your controller you declare a model which you can send to the view. The view will then be able to handle the values it was given. You can then post your values in your model back to the controller if you wish to handle them further.

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult MyView(){
 var model = new MyViewModel{
   SomeProperty = "Hello"
}
}
```

MODEL

```
[Display(Name = "Greeting")]
public string SomeProperty{get; set;}
```

VIEW

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
```

If you want to change it whilst on the view, depedning on the nature of your problem, use either a form to post back to the controller or jquery/javascript to alter the variable.